# how to control process in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, process, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I want to run several process in parallel without giving cpu too much work so that cpu can also do other jobs.

In python, I will use os.system to call some binary. And theses call are independent and can be parallel. But these binary may run for different length of time.

What I want to do is for example, always keep 8 of them run in parallel, if some one exit early, then start another one.

what I am doing now is like this:

```
count = 0
for f in files:
    count = count + 1
    cmd = exe 
    if (count != 8):
        cmd = cmd + " &"
    else:
        count = 0
    os.sytem(cmd)
```

but this will be not ideal if the `cmd` without & runs too long or too short.

I also tried multiprocessing module,

```
p=Pool(8)
print(p.map(f,list_of_args))
```

but in this case I am not running 8 processes in parallel for most of the time. Since some of them exit early.

There is no need for synchronization.

I have 16 cpu cores and I want half of them(8 processes to runs in parallel)

Answer (score 1):

You'd better not to use [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) but [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) as it is more powerful and safe. Moreover `subprocess.Popen` does not block on call so you don't need to append any '&' at the end of the command.

For the question itself, you need to know that Operating Systems are quite good in balancing automatically the workload so you should not worry about idling processes vs running ones. Just launch your workers with the `Pool` and let them run until needed without worrying of 'wasting' any resource. An idling process takes just a bit of memory and that's it.

When it comes to improving your code, something you might want to use is a Pool of threads instead of a Pool of processes. This due to the fact that your workers are simply waiting for other ones to finish so threads are better than processes for that.

If you can use Python 3 something like this will do the job for you.

```
import subprocess
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def function(myfile):
    command = ('watever', 'you', 'want', 'to', 'do', 'with', myfile)
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.communicate()


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    future = executor.map(function, files)
    future.result()
```

Comment: I think operating system will do context switch with this code? say if files is a list of 100000 items, then may be I will need to wait a very long time for one of them to finish since you need to do a lot of context switch.

Comment: If you pair the amount of workers with the number of CPUs the amount of context switches would be paltry. If you spawn too many processes instead, the context switch could become noticeable.